# Silver and gold tag-specific badges should start with an upper-case letter

Tags: feature-request, badges

Tags are mostly all lowercase, e.g. `python`.

If you receive a silver badge for this tag (400x upvotes) you get a silver badge with the same name (`python`).

This is inconsistent with the names of the normal badges (such as `Tumbleweed` or `Yearling`) which all start with an uppercase letter.

I think the first letter of these tag specific badges should be capitalized.

Comment: ick.  no, keep them the same as the tags, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would then create badges named like `Iphone` that look kinda weird, imo.

Anyways I like the fact that they are different: you can easily distinguish them from the "real" badges. If a tag with the same name as a badge becomes popular, then it would be the only way to distinguish the two.