# Add a prefix for tag-specific silver or gold badges

Tags: feature-request, badges

A prefix would help to differentiate tag-specific badges from the others (like `Yearling` or `Tumbleweed`).

Also it would help with the fact that they are a little bit inconsistent because [they can (contrary to the others) start with a lowercase letter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45358/silver-and-gold-specific-tags-should-be-capitalized).

They could be something like:

`Master: python` (gold badge, 1000x upvotes)
`Expert: python` (silver badge, 400x upvotes)

('master' and 'expert' may not be the clearest distinction, suggestions welcome !)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like this idea. Aside from anything else, when I earn a tag-related badge and see the notification, I currently need to check whether it was the gold or silver one. Of course you could experiment with different formats:

```
Master: python
Master of "python"
Master (python)
```

etc

I'm not sure that "Master" and "Expert" are the right words though - it wasn't immediately obvious to me which was gold and which was silver without reading your extra description.

Comment: +1: I agree with this idea but not with the proposed "Master: %s" format

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Kop: I agree that the current proposal isn't too clear, open for suggestions.

Comment: @Jon: The "need to check whether it was the gold or silver one" is a very poor reason IMHO. First of all, it's not that hard, it's *just one click*. And secondly, people have to do that for *all other badges*, too. Even if you personally happen to know by heart whether Guru, Populist, or Pundit are silver or gold, many (if not most) other users don't.

Comment: And lastly, this is probably the only scenario where the prefix would provide a clarification. In all other situations, it would actually be pure noise (since in all other situations you can immediately see what color a badge has).

Comment: @RegDwight: For other badges there's no ambiguity about which badge you've received. In this case the same name is given to two different achievements. It's the equivalent of "nice answer" being used for the current "nice answer" *and* "good answer". It's not a case of caring about whether the resulting badge was gold or silver - it's a case of caring about whether the badge represents 1000 votes or 400. There's a subtle difference.

Answer (score 2):

What about `journeyman` and `master`? That's the sub-title of [The Pragmatic Programmer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/020161622X).

Answer (score 0):

If you must do this, I don't think adding  a second adjective to the gold/silver badges is a good idea - think of gold & silver medals at the Olympics - there is no need for  a second adjective. Whynot:

```
Gold: python (1000x upvotes)
Silver: python (400x upvotes)
```

Comment: Oh, the redundancy.....